# How to replace elements in a deque object?

Tags: c++

I've tried everyting from the standart API.

`insert`, `push_front`, `assign`.

I have a deque object:

```
std::deque<byte> data(100, 0);
```

I need to insert elements into the first element up to the last but when i try, it inserts elements into the "new" deque, after which the 100 elements is just 0ed.

Comment: `data[index] = value;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica is there any ways to do that using standart api? I suppose there should be.

Comment: What do you meant the standard api?  `operator[]` is part of `std::deque`

Comment: I think the question your asking is how to _replace_ the elements in a deque object. `push_front()` inserts a new element to the front of the deque and increases its size by 1, which it seems like you don't want.

Comment: @Richard Stop moving the goal posts.  Put what you really want in your question, and you get an answer that answers that.  When you keep wanting more or keep changing what you have it makes it really hard for us to help you.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica alright, it worked. I was overcomplicate things no idea why.
(obj*)[] works fine for me now. Speaking of standart functions, not operators. How would you do that using them?

Comment: @Richard: The operator overloads *are* functions. `data.at(index) = value;` can do the job with an explicit function call, but it's just a bounds-checked version of `operator[]`. There is no "replace with both index and new value as arguments" function, because there doesn't need to be; returning a reference allows reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do a simple loop and push those onto an initially empty deque:

```
std::deque<byte> data();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     data.push_front(i);
}
```

Comment: i need the deque to contain fixed element size at the beginning.

Comment: In that case use `data[i] = someValue` like @NathanOliver-reinstate-monica suggested.